# Keep multi lined (JSON) block into a single line string

Tags: json, jq

```
$ echo '{"errno": 0,"return_type": 1,"block_list": [0,1,2,3,4],"uploadid": "xxx","request_id": 10}' | jq -C
{
  "errno": 0,
  "return_type": 1,
  "block_list": [
    0,
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4
  ],
  "uploadid": "xxx",
  "request_id": 10
}
```

How do I keep the lines in `block_list` on one line?.

```
{
  "errno": 0,
  "return_type": 1,
  "block_list": [0,1,2,3,4],
  "uploadid": "xxx",
  "request_id": 10
}
```

Comment: According to the [JSON specs](https://www.json.org/), an array can be represented with an arbitrary amount of whitespaces around the values and the commas. Therefore, inserting or omitting them is at the JSON processor's choice. One will do it one way, another one the other, and so do `jq` and `jq -c`. If you do care about the presence or absence of whitespaces in a specific way, they become data, and you should opt for a data type that provides for it: strings. You can turn your array into one using `.block_list |= tostring`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach that will work with your example and many like it, but please understand its limitations:

```
jq 'walk(if type == "array" and length < 10 then "<Q>" + tostring + "<Q>" else . end)' |
    sed '/"<Q>[[].*[]]<Q>"/ {s/"<Q>[[]/[/; s/[]]<Q>"/]/;}'
```

Here's a variant that avoids problems with arrays-within-arrays:

```
jq 'walk(if type == "array" and length < 10 and all(type != "string" or (startswith("<Q>") | not))
         then "<Q>" + tostring + "<Q>" else . end)' |
    sed '/"<Q>[[].*[]]<Q>"/ {s/"<Q>[[]/[/g; s/[]]<Q>"/]/g;}'
```